# Why Hadoop FileSystem.get method needs to know full URI and not just scheme

Tags: java, hadoop

Is it possible to use  an instance of Hadoop FileSystem created from any valid  hdfs url to be used  again for reading and writing  different hdfs urls.I have tried the following

```
String url1 = "hdfs://localhost:54310/file1.txt";
String url2 = "hdfs://localhost:54310/file2.txt";
String url3 = "hdfs://localhost:54310/file3.txt";

//Creating filesystem using url1
FileSystem fileSystem = FileSystem.get(URI.create(url1), conf);

//Using same filesystem with url2 and url3  
InputStream in = fileSystem.open(new Path(url2));
OutputStream out = fileSystem.create(new Path(url3));
```

This works.But will this cause any other issues.

Answer (score 9):

You can certainly create a single `FileSystem` with your scheme and adress and then get it via the `FileSystem`.

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.set("fs.default.name","hdfs://localhost:54310");
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
InputStream is = fs.open(new Path("/file1.txt"));
```

Answer (score 0):

For different dfs paths, methods create/open will fail. Look at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem#checkPath method.